# React - onChange don't work when attach without parentheses?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, onchange, parentheses

I have seen something weird when working with `onChange` in React.

The basic flow is to listen for changes of `this.props.tableBody` and trigger autoscroll to the table bottom. The `tableBody` is a list of items.

I use react class component and have bound the function already.

```
class ProgressTable extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onTableChangeHandler = this.onTableChangeHandler.bind(this);
    }

    onTableChangeHandler() {
        console.log("hi from onTableChangeHandler");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="table-body-container" onChange={this.onTableChangeHandler}> // not work
                {this.props.tableBody}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

As usual, the code should be fine.

But something weird happened here. The `onChange`, which should invoke `onTableChangeHandler` function now doesn't.

I have tried to figure out what is happening here and found that if I add `()` to the `onChange` attached function like this, the code is working and listen for the changes correctly except for the first redundant call when component `render`.

```
<div className="table-body-container" onChange={this.onTableChangeHandler()}> // work like usual
    {this.props.tableBody}
</div>
```

Furthermore, I have tried this and it also works.

```
<div className="table-body-container" onChange={console.log("hi")}> // "hi"
    {this.props.tableBody}
</div>
```

Can you show me what and why this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onChange` event handler is used for elements like `input` or `select`. When you type in an input element it invokes the `onChange` but `div`'s don't "change" as such so nothing will happen.

If you are looking for something to happen when the div is clicked you need to use `onClick` handler instead.

What you are doing here (`onChange={this.onTableChangeHandler()}`) is essentially manually calling your function immediately when the component renders (and on every subsequent render) and that's why it **looks** like it's working even when you use it in a handler that shouldn't really work when used on divs, but in reality this is just bad practice.